# ¿Cómo consultar tabla externa en MySql?

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

Que tal tengo la siguiente problemática:

Estoy haciendo una consulta de registros para mi una vista index en Laravel. la cual es la siguiente:

```
$datos = DB::table('detalle_peticions')
        ->join('peticion_materials', 'peticion_materials.id_peticion', '=', 'detalle_peticions.id_peticion')
        ->join('materiales', 'materiales.id_material', '=', 'detalle_peticions.id_material')
        ->select(['detalle_peticions.id_detalle',
        'peticion_materials.id_personal', 'peticion_materials.fecha_peticion', 'peticion_materials.observaciones',
        'materiales.id_material','materiales.codigo', 'materiales.nombre', 'materiales.precio',
        'detalle_peticions.cantidadP', 'total'])
        ->orderBy('peticion_materials.id_personal', 'asc')
        ->paginate(20);
        return view('DetallePeticion.index', compact('datos'));
```

Me retorna la siguiente vista..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta es ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me muestre el nombre del personal y no su id que tomo desde el join?

Muestro Diagrama ER

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo la consulta desde la tabla "detalle_peticions".

Comment: Así como le estás planteando podrías hacer otro join para poder hacer un select de la columna en la tabla personals. Pero en mi opinión, te va a facilitar la vida usar eloquent, el orm de laravel , definir las relaciones en los modelos y hacer las consultas a travel de los modelos y relaciones

Comment: Ya lo intente pero no me funciono, y en este caso no use eloquent ya que es algo ineficiente ya que se manejaran muchos datos y hago distintas consultas de busqueda en tiempo real en este cado DB es podría decir mejor

Comment: una de 2,
1 usar `BD::select('cualquier select que quieras');`
,2 has una vista en la base de las tablas que muestre solo los datos que desees y la llamas con un nuevo modelo de eloquent.
por funcionalidad recomiendo la 2.  
Nota: eloquent es bueno pero no par todo.

Comment: Puedes hacer **otra consulta**, donde saques todos los usuarios, y luego en la vista recorres los usuarios, y en caso de que el `id usuario` coincida con el que tienes en la vista, escribir el nombre de usuario